# Gatsby Js Pagination : start root page at desired page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I'm trying to build my own blog with GatsbyJs and wordpress as headless CMS.

I'm trying to paginate my posts pages, I've found a way but the posts start at blog/1. How can I do for formatting the path in order to set the 1st page at blog/ ?

[*I'm a total noobie in developing, and trying to learn by my self*]

Here my gatsby-node.js

````
const path = require('path');

const allPostsQuery = `{
  allWpPost {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        slug
      }
    }
  }
}`;



const createPaginationPages = (component, totalItems, base, context, createPage) => {
  const pageSize = 4;
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
  return Array.from({length: pageCount}).map((_, index) => createPage({
    path: `${base}/${ index+ 1}`,
    component,
    context: {
      base,
      limit: pageSize,
      skip: index * pageSize,
      pageCount,
      currentPage: index + 1,
      ...context
    },
  }));
};
 

// création de page pour chaque article
const createPostPages = ({allWpPost}, createPage) => {
  return allWpPost.edges.map(({node}) => createPage({
    path: `/blog/${node.slug}`,
    component: path.resolve('./src/templates/post.js'),
    context: {slug: node.slug}
  }));
};

//création de la page avec tous les articles 
const createPostsPages = ({allWpPost}, createPage) => createPaginationPages(
  path.resolve('./src/templates/blog.js'),
  allWpPost.edges.length,
  '/blog',
  {},
  createPage
);

exports.createPages = ({graphql, actions}) => {
  const {createPage} = actions;
  return graphql(allPostsQuery).then(({errors, data}) => {
    if (errors) return Promise.reject(errors);
    return [
      createPostPages(data, createPage),
      createPostsPages(data, createPage),
    ];
  });
};```




Thank you
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your logic here:

```
const createPaginationPages = (component, totalItems, base, context, createPage) => {
  const pageSize = 4;
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
  return Array.from({length: pageCount}).map((_, index) => createPage({
    path: `${index === 0 ? `${base}/` : `${base}/${index + 1}`}`,
    component,
    context: {
      base,
      limit: pageSize,
      skip: index * pageSize,
      pageCount,
      currentPage: index + 1,
      ...context
    },
  }));
};
```

The ternary condition here does the trick:

```
path: `${index === 0 ? `${base}/` : `${base}/${index + 1}`}`,
```

If your `index` is `0`, the path will be the `base`, if not, it will concatenate `index + 1`.